# Участник с большей репутацией, отклоняет предложенную правку участника с меньшей репутацией и следом делает абсолютно те же изменения

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки, отклонённые-правки

Я [предложила правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/852974) кода в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1307799/176217):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правка была отклонена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом участник, который отклонил правку, делает абсолютно [идентичные правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1307799/revisions) (ревизия 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поясните, это норма ?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145787/discussion-on-question-by-dev18------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обсуждаемая проверка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/852974

> "Я предложила правку кода в ответе:", "Правка была отклонена."

Смотрим правку в режиме "В две колонки с Markdown", видим, что было установлено обозначение языка подсветки `C` (что не соответствует метке вопроса `C#`):

[image: Скриншот]

> Потом участник, который отклонил правку, делает абсолютно [идентичные правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1307799/revisions) (ревизия 2):

Опять же, смотрим правку "В две колонки с Markdown"

[image: Скриншот]

Видно, что правка явно не идентичная предложенной, я оставил выделение кода отступами, просто уменьшил отступы, где они были излишни. Соответственно, я не добавлял никакое обозначение подсветки. Нужная подсветка автоматически определяется по метке языка вопроса.

В принципе, не обязательно язык подсветки указывать, если в вопросе нет конкурирующих меток (например, `java` + `html` для шаблона страницы, либо есть какие-нибудь конфиги, для которых не должна использоваться подсветка основного языка).

Если нужно всё-таки явно указать конкретную подсветку языка, лучше посмотреть на странице описания метки в самом низу (заходим в метку, жмём "Подробнее..."). Например, для метки [C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) указано обозначение подсветки `lang-cs`:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: В сухом остатке, стоило принять и `C` заменить на `lang-cs`, только и всего.

Comment: @aepot можно было принять, а можно было и отклонить. Не считаю, что insolor сделал что-то не так.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я же явно писал в комментах выше, что я тоже не считаю что он сделал что-то не так.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я думаю в данном контексте "стоило" нужно понимать как рекомендацию, а не что именно так нужно было сделать, и больше никак)

Comment: Вердикт: оправдан!  

Comment: @insolor благодарю за реактивный ответ, приму во внимание на будущее, чтоб не было *боли* проверяющих. ```lang-cs``` по предложению @aepot я постараюсь запомнить, чтоб использовать также и в своих вопросах.

Comment: Честно говоря, я всё-таки считаю решение сомнительным. aepot уже писал, что есть `lang-cs`, то есть можно было не "отклонять и править", а "принимать и править"

Comment: @Зонтик можно было, но было по-другому. В принципе, даже если бы можно было отмотать обратно, я бы все равно сделал так же, именно потому что обозначение языка подсветки не соответствует. Вариант "принять, потом поправить" - это как раз более сомнительный вариант, я не вижу никакого вменяемого довода за него кроме заботы о другом участнике.

Comment: "забота о другом участнике" - это не маловажный аргумент. Конкретно в этом случае я на вашей стороне, потому что хоть и были благие намерения, но пострадала реализация. Я всё же считаю что "Принять и править" нужно использовать если есть чем дополнить правку, но никак не переделывать работу (максимум какие-то мелкие вещи типа опечаток) за участника, только потому что он постарался. Но если бы вы действительно просто сделали те же самые изменения (быть может дополнив чем-то своим), то именно из-за "забота о другом участнике" я был бы против вашего решения

Comment: Отмену, что сам код языка для C# - это `cs`, а `lang-`- всего лишь префикс для использования в синтаксисе разметки через HTML комментарии. Не пытайтесь писать в маркдауне ```lang-cs

Comment: @PavelMayorov если я использую **```** после какую *абривиатуру* необходимо указать ?

Comment: @Dev18 просто `cs`, см. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md

Comment: @Dev18, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/660517/revisions я принял и отредактировал) Нет особого смысла оформлять сниппетом, если сниппет в итоге не запускается (я не нашел как подключить в сниппеты gulp (что бы это ни было), и возможно ли это вообще)

Comment: @insolor я заметила, и даже зашла посмотреть, что вы поставили (javascript), я читала вопросы, и наткнулась на этот гулп, который был тусклый, и подсмотрела как сделал отвечающий, и переняла у него. код подсветился, но вот пробелы как то изменились. Честно сказать, я бы вообще не удивилась, если бы не приняли именно этот вариант. А напротив подсмотрела бы как делает исправляющий и запомнила. а так как будто меня прям ой жалко жалко... и вот жест. Это я к тому, что для меня важно ЗНАТЬ ПОЧЕМУ ОТКЛОНИЛИ. а не сам факт, и вот из этого я тут вопросы задаю. Надеюсь вы меня поняли. Вам спасибо,

Comment: что отписалиь еще и тут для статистики

Comment: @Dev18 понял, хорошо)

Comment: @insolor [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518795/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js) отвечающий использует такую же [абривиатуру](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d4HA.png) , что я предложила при правке, что вы указали выше, со снипетами...

Comment: @ksa подскажите, как работают эти снипеты ?

Comment: @Dev18 там отдельный "редактор" для сниппетов: кнопка "Фрагмент кода JavaScript и т.д.". Нажимаете, потом вставляете в нужные окошки нужные части кода, слева еще настройки можно подшаманить. Я во фронте ничего особо не понимаю, но часто просто вставка кода в нужные окошки срабатывает, и сниппет оказывается рабочим. Можно и вручную в сниппет превращать, но нужно откуда-то тэги копипастить.

Comment: @insolor
 ну такое использование не корректно? Ведь вы же исправили мою правку. а я один в один как в примере выше ссылки сделала

Comment: @Dev18 преимущество сниппета перед просто выделением кодом - то что сниппет можно запустить. Потыкайте, например, "выполнить код" в ответах здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1518795/1365. Если в итоге сниппет не запускается (как при вашей правке), то и особого профита от выделения сниппетом нет. Т.е. тут скорее не корректно/некорректно, а имеет смысл/не имеет смысла.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145920/discussion-between-dev18-and-insolor).

Comment: @insolor не согласна...можно обсудить

Answer (score 1):

Почитал дискуссию, но сильно не погружался.

Мне кажется, что делать правки ради правки - не верное направление. Правки существуют для того, чтобы было удобно отвечающим и ищущим ответы. Использование сниппетов не только позволяет запускать код, но и копировать его в ответ (удобно, но я тоже редко фронта касаюсь).

Для ТС, когда появляется правка в очереди на проверку, нет уж очень большого выбора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, если вы ошиблись в правке (как я понял не верно был указан язык подсветки синтаксиса), то проверяющий верно выбрал "Отколнить и править".

Основываясь на скринах от @insolor, вы не улучшили ответ (читаемость, ошибки или опечатки), вы снизили его качество или оставили на том же уровне. Ваше возмущение по данному поводу понятно, но не верно.

Совет, которому можно не следовать: используйте правки для реального улучшения вопросов/ответов.

Comment: / Dmitry ну очень жаль, что вы отвечате на вопрос, не `погрузившись` и делаете свои выводы по поводу возмущения (где вы его вообще заметили?) а также даете советы и считаете, что я снизила качество вопроса/ответа, не посмотрев и не проанализировав. Все эти доводы/мнение ошибочны лишь потому, что визуально НЕ БЫЛО НИКАКОЙ РАЗНИЦЫ. и **именно** это меня и подвело к вопросу, что нет НИ объяснений ПОЧЕМУ, а визуально ТАЖЕ картинка. Поверьте, все свои правки, я делаю для РЕАЛЬНОГО (аккуратист) улучшения, уж к этому точно вы не так подошли.

Comment: @Dev18 учитывайте не только визуал, но способы поиска ответов/вопросов. Визуальное восприятие очень субъективное понятие. То, что мне будет казаться верным/красивым/приятным глазу совсем не будет нравиться очень многим. Очень много внимания не очень важной теме.

Comment: ну вот тут вы сами себе противоречите... `то проверяющий верно выбрал "Отколнить и править".` ===> исходя из вашего комментария ему надобно бы `ОТКЛОНИТЬ=>Эта правка не улучшает сообщение`

Comment: @Dev18 дискуссия в пустую. Поднакопите немного репутации и вам не будет необходимости согласовывать ваши правки с другими участниками сообщества. И может чуть по спокойней к этому относиться? Ваша правка не улучшает сообщение (факт), все остальное на усмотрение проверяющего. Если бы вы не создали данную правку, то никто бы ничего и подправлял

Comment: @Dmitry вопрос уже давно решен, к чему тут на ровном месте разборки разводить?

Comment: @insolor это не разборки, пытался показать ТСу, что включает в себя проверка правок. И может в дальшейшем предупредить вопросы на эту тему. Но ТС, близко к сердцу воспринимает, не предполагал, что так

Comment: @Dmitry да уже все обсудили и в комментариях и в чатике, уже все дальнейшие вопросы "предупредили". Правка в принципе полезная (чисто визуальные правки полезны), но частично спорная. То что правка на усмотрение проверяющего - как бы да, но это не значит, что у проверяющего нельзя уточнить, почему он отклонил/принял правку. Я воспринимаю вопрос именно как уточняющий вопрос, почему было принято решение.

Comment: @insolor я только приветствую и считаю все это хорошим тоном. И сам всегда отвечаю на подобные темы, когда это касается меня. На счет основного вопроса, то вряд ли многие пройдут весь этот путь в чате, а вот ответ будет на виду. Не только одному справшивающему ТСу это может быть полезно